# Airflow 1.9 - SSHOperator doesn't seem to work?

Tags: airflow

Upgraded to v1.9 and I'm having a hard time getting the `SSHOperator` to work. It was working w/ v1.8.2.

## Code

```
dag = DAG('transfer_ftp_s3', default_args=default_args,schedule_interval=None)

task = SSHOperator(
       ssh_conn_id='ssh_node',
       task_id="check_ftp_for_new_files",
       command="echo 'hello world'",
       do_xcom_push=True,
       dag=dag,)
```

## Error

```
[2018-02-19 06:48:02,691] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: Traceback (most recent call last):
[2018-02-19 06:48:02,691] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/bin/airflow", line 27, in <module>
[2018-02-19 06:48:02,692] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:     args.func(args)
[2018-02-19 06:48:02,693] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 392, in run
[2018-02-19 06:48:02,695] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:     pool=args.pool,
[2018-02-19 06:48:02,695] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 50, in wrapper
[2018-02-19 06:48:02,696] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:     result = func(*args, **kwargs)
[2018-02-19 06:48:02,696] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1496, in _run_raw_task
[2018-02-19 06:48:02,696] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2018-02-19 06:48:02,697] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py", line 146, in execute
[2018-02-19 06:48:02,697] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:     raise AirflowException("SSH operator error: {0}".format(str(e)))
[2018-02-19 06:48:02,698] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: SSH operator error: 'bool' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: The SSH operator has been reworked: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md#ssh-hook-updates-along-with-new-ssh-operator--sftp-operator

Comment: @FokkoDriesprong yeah, but it looks like he's changed the call signature to match `SSHOperator`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as [AIRFLOW-2122](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2122) check your connections setting , make sure the extra's value using a string instead of a bool

Comment: for example: {"key_file": "/Users/XXX/.ssh/xxx", "no_host_key_check": "true"}